# How to refresh the page after redirecting from another page in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I want to refresh the page after redirecting from another page in angularjs.Is it posiible? if yes please help

Answer (score 0):

You can call `location.reload()` (or `location.reload(true)` to force it to load from the server) in the controller which is used in the page you are redirecting to.

That will reload the current document